# Integrate Using Gauss Laguerre Quadrature

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Can we integrate a function F(x) using Gauss Laguerre Quadrature when it is not of the form:  [$$\int_0^{+\infty} F(x) dx$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature)

An example in my numerical methods book seems to imply that it can; however, we have been only used used this technique in class to approximate well behaved integrals on finite bounds of integration so it is unclear how/if the technique can be used for something more difficult-

The function is:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x}(1+x^2)^{-1}dx\
$$

The professor dropped the question from a homework and some students said that it could not be solved stating it is not convergent, but I was wondering if someone who is better at Numerical Analysis and approximation knew for sure.

Can this problem be solved using Gauss Laguerre Quadrature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^x}{1+x^2} dx$$ diverges. However, the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-\vert x\vert}}{1+x^2} dx$$
converges and is a good candidate for trying Gauss Laguerre quadratures.

Also, Gauss Laguerre quadratures are precisely for integration from $0$ to $\infty$. For other finite bounds, you might look at other Gaussian quadratures. The defacto Gaussian quadrature on finite intervals is the [Gauss-Legendre quadrature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gauss.E2.80.93Legendre_quadrature).

However, if you know *more* about the integrand, we could obtain a lot of other different [Gaussian quadratures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Other_forms).

Comment: If Gauss Laguerre quadratures are precisely for integration from 0 to $\infty$ why is  $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-\vert x\vert}}{1+x^2} dx$$ a good candidate for Gauss Laguerre quadratures?

Comment: @AshleyCole $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-\vert x \vert}}{1+x^2} = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-\vert x \vert}}{1+x^2}$$